# C++: Template Template Member of a Template Parameter as a Parameter to a Template Class Expecting a Template Template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, template-templates

First of all, apologies for the horrible title. I was experimenting with the C++20 `is_detected` functionality. `is_detected` basically takes two template parameters, one is a higher-order type which performs checking and the other one is the type to be checked. I ran into problems in the following scenario:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <type_traits>

// kind of how std::experimental::is_detected is implemented
template <template <typename> typename Checker, typename T, typename = void>
struct is_detected: std::false_type {};

template <template <typename> typename Checker, typename T>
struct is_detected<Checker, T, std::void_t<Checker<T>>>: std::true_type {};

struct Foo {
    template <typename T>
    using Checker = decltype(std::declval<T>().foo());

    template <typename T>
    static constexpr void call(T &t) {
        t.foo();
    }
};

template <typename T>
using GlobalChecker = decltype(std::declval<T>().foo());

template <typename T>
struct Wrapper {
    template <typename U>
    using LocalChecker = typename T::template Checker<U>;
    //                               ^^^^^^^^ clang and msvc require template keyword
    //                                        gcc doesn't require it

    template <typename U>
    constexpr void conditional_call(U &u) const noexcept {
        if constexpr (
            is_detected<
                typename T::Checker,// !!! COMPILE ERROR !!!
                                    // works for
                                    // GlobalChecker,
                                    // LocalChecker and
                                    // Foo::Checker, though.
                std::decay_t<U>>
                ::value) {
            Foo::call(u);
        }
        else {
            puts("fallback");
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    struct {
        void foo() {
            puts("heyy!");
        }
    } t;

    Wrapper<Foo> w;
    w.conditional_call(t); // heyy! (if foo didn't exist, then fallback)
}
```

If I alias the `Checker` in the class scope using the `using LocalChecker = typename T::template Checker<U>;`, it works; however, I want to learn if there is another way without using `using`. In addition, do I need the `template` in this `using` definition? Because Clang and GCC disagree on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with C++17, you do not need the `template` keyword between a `::` and a member template specialization name in certain contexts that can only name a type, including the *typename-specifier* syntax, which is used in the `LocalChecker` alias template. So clang and MSVC are wrong to reject that line without the `template`, and possibly haven't yet implemented this change.

C++14 [temp.names]/4:

> When the name of a member template specialization appears after `.` or `->` in a *postfix-expression* or after a *nested-name-specifier* in a *qualified-id*, and the object expression of the *postfix-expression* is type-dependent
>   or the *nested-name-specifier* in the *qualified-id* refers to a dependent type, but the name is not a member of the current instantiation (14.6.2.1), the member template name must be prefixed by the keyword `template`. Otherwise the name is assumed to name a non-template.

was replaced with [C++17 [temp.names]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp#names-4):

> The keyword `template` is said to appear at the top level in a *qualified-id* if it appears outside of a *template-argument-list* or *decltype-specifier*. In a *qualified-id* of a *declarator-id* or in a *qualified-id* formed by a *class-head-name* or *enum-head-name*, the keyword `template` shall not appear at the top level. In a *qualified-id* used as the name in a *typename-specifier*, *elaborated-type-specifier*, *using-declaration*, or *class-or-decltype*, an optional keyword `template` appearing at the top level is ignored. In these contexts, a `<` token is always assumed to introduce a *template-argument-list*. In all other contexts, when naming a template specialization of a member of an unknown specialization ([temp.dep.type]), the member template name shall be prefixed by the keyword `template`.

Since the rules above only require the keyword `template` when a member template specialization is named, not just the member template itself, it would seem plain `T::Checker`, in addition to `T::template Checker`, ought to work at the part of the example using `is_detected`. (We don't want `typename`, since we're naming the alias template, not a type which is a specialization of that template.) But it's not clear why adding a template should make a difference in when a compiler does or doesn't need help determining the meaning. The open [CWG issue 1478](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1478) is related.

In any case, the compilers do seem to like it better with the `template` hint: your program with `is_detected<T::template Checker,`... compiles successfully on clang++, g++, and msvc: [see on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/uJfksy).

Comment: Implementations are not entirely consistent here: there’s a [relevant Core issue](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1478).

Comment: @DavisHerring Oh, right. I missed that both versions of paragraph 4 are talking about a template specialization, not a template name. (And does the compiler need to know at template definition whether the name is a type or a template? There's also the requirement that when an the name of a class template in its own scope is used as a template argument, the ambiguity between naming the template and naming the current instantiation class type depends on the corresponding template parameter, in exactly the way that a non-type vs. type ambiguity like `TT<int()>` does not!)

Comment: Because of that very ambiguity, compilers already have to handle the case of a template argument of unknown kind (even after the disambiguation you mention), so there’s not much point in telling them.